# How to copy files in VC++ ?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I want to copy the files present in a flash drive into hard drives and then run them using a VC++ application. I have VS 2008..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `FindFile()` to figure out what files are in the folder..

```
CopyFile(_T("c:\\test"), _T("c:\\test1"), true);
```

Then `ShellExecute(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Use [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx) / [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(v=VS.85).aspx) / [FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413(VS.85).aspx) to enumerate the files on your flash drive.  If you determine the file is an executable (say by checking for a `.exe` extension), then you use [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851(VS.85).aspx) to copy them to the hard drive you want.

Once they are copied you can use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) to start them or else [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908775.aspx) if you want control of the process via a process handle.